# C# Zyan Framework: fire event restricted to certain client

Tags: c#

i've a couple of questions regarding Zyan Framework.
Given that I have an event which many clients hook up to, can I just inform a specific one by sessionid? For example, i've a clients hashset, and many sessions stored to it. But how can i send a message to an certain client, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Solution came by itself.

Create new

```
HashSet<IClient> _clients = new HashSet<IClient>();
```

Where IClient interfaces contains session information and instance of the session's registered component, which one wrapped with necessary methods like Send, Notify etc. (and they're will fire events, listened on the client side). On new client authenticated and logged on, where just creating new instance of IClient implementation, and then adding it to our HashSet